# not getting the initial value by default in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

```
 <html>
  <script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <body ng-controller="firstController">
   <div ng-app="">
        FirstName <input type="text"  ng-model="first"/>
        LastName <input type="text"  ng-model="last"/>
        Welcome {{first + " " + last}} 
   </div>
   <script>        <!-- script for the controller
        function firstController($scope){
         $scope.first="HELLO";
         $scope.last="ALL";
        }
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

After running this code i m getting two text boxes with empty strings 
         (no "HELLO" & "ALL" in the text box)and if I writing anything in the         text boxes it comes up along with the 'Welcome'.Also if I put ng-controller      after ng-app it wont work.

I copied this code from some tutorial. There it works for them.
         Please help me to find out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The script runs after the page loads. Move the `<script>` outside the body, under the `<script src="angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`. This way, the script will execute before and the bindings may work.

EDIT:

Also: your app should be outside your controller (`ng-app` should be before `ng-controller`) because controllers are parts of apps.

And you need the following after your function declaration (in JS):

```
var app = angular.module('',[]);//This string must match the value of ng-app
app.controller('firstController',firstController);
//This string has to match the value of ng-controller.
```

Comment: I put ng-app before ng-controller long back itself . but still not working.the same code which i pasted here works in the tutorial. thts y i m confused.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the ng-init to call that method on page load like this

```
<body ng-controller="firstController" 
      ng-init="firstController()">
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I think your ng-controller must be inside of your ng-app scope.

Second: Try to define your module and your controller like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="myApp">  
  <body>
   <div ng-controller="firstController">
        FirstName <input type="text"  ng-model="first"/>
        LastName <input type="text"  ng-model="last"/>
        Welcome {{first + " " + last}} 
   </div>
   <script>        
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

      app.controller("firstController", function($scope) {
          $scope.first="HELLO";
          $scope.last="ALL";
      });
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: ur code is also working bcz of naming the ng-app and related code. but in that tutorial the same piece of code which i pasted here works .

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code

```html
 <html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="first"><br>
 Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="last"><br>
 <br>
 Welcome: {{first + " " + last}}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.first= "HELLO";
    $scope.last= "ALL";
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: ur code is working bcz of naming the ng-app and related app. but in that tutorial the same piece of code which i pasted here works .thts y i m confused.